# Bokeh Websocket closing connection : Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: json, websocket, bokeh

I am using bokeh for Data visualization and when I use a python callback to get a table and a plot of large dataset I get this error in the browser console  "closing connection : Unexpected end of JSON input failed to excute 'close'..."
Is there any solution for that problem !!

Comment: It's not possible to speculate without a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.